# Detect multiple div elements in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/c7nS5/light/), it can only detect one `DOM` element. If I have multiple elements that need to be detected, like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7nS5/22/). It will ignore the second `div` tag.

does anyone know how I can pass multiple `div` elements in the `viewbag` into this function?

```
$.fn.is_on_screen = function () {

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

    if ($('.target').is_on_screen()) {
        alert('hey');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you call  `$('.target').is_on_screen()` only the first element in the array is considere which is the first DOM element with class `target`

To work around that write something like :

```
function isTargetVisble() {
    var retunVal = false;
    $('.target').each(function() {
        if( $(this).is_on_screen() ) {
            retunVal = true;
        }
    });
    return retunVal;
}
```

And Use it

```
if( isTargetVisble() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
```

instead of

```
if( $('.target').is_on_screen() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7nS5/23/)

Comment: Thanks Sreekesh. Really appreciate for your help!